# Postman requests keep creating new conversations

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

I've deployed the "pizza" dialog to my Bluemix account.  I'm using Postman to verify the REST interactions prior to my coding implementation.  I'm able to retrieve the dialog id using the dialog REST GET.  Taking the returned dialog id I establish a new conversation (leave client_id and conversation_id) empty:

https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/ee93cf6e-8718-4524-b10c-4f20fee90883/conversation

I use the returned conversation id to send another conversation request but I first set in the header the conversation_id, and the input value to "A large Pizza"

https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/ee93cf6e-8718-4524-b10c-4f20fee90883/conversation

Rather than getting the next turn in the dialog asking for toppings I get a new conversation id and new client id, and input asking me again for what size pizza I'd like to order.

Should I be able to test the dialog interaction using Postman, and why are my subsequent dialog requests all being treated as new conversation requests?

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are setting the conversation ID in the header so I am going to assume you may be passing that ID parameter incorrectly. According to the [Watson Dialog API Explorer](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/dialog/api/v1/#converse) it states that if you do not pass in a conversation_id it will start a new conversation. Since you pass the converation_id incorrectly it thinks you did not provide one and will start a new conversation with you.

Since you are using Postman, try setting the conversation_id in the Body of the POST and not in the header.